# Where should be placed resource files in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to build a simple app with Cordova, React and framework7. My simplify project structure is as fallows:

```
app
 |_ assets-src
 |_ build
 |_ cordova
    |_ platforms
       |_ios
       |_android
    |_ plugins
    |_ wwww
 |_ node_modules
 |_ src
 |_ www
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui,viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#007aff">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <title>dianovator</title>
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <-- HERE is the problem -->
    <script src="lib/drivers/mydriver/driver.js"></script>
    <script src="serialeDriver.js"></script>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have placed the lib/drivers/mydriver/driver.js and serialeDriver.js in thw www root folder and also in www inside cordova folder, but this files are not copied when I build my apk:

[image]

So because this files are not copied in assets I get 404 when I try the apk.

Where should more exactly be placed this files in order to be copied in assets folder from apk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer. If you have resource file they need to be in :

```
your_project\cordova\platforms\android\platform_www
```

Same path for ios, just the platform name is changed:

```
your_project\cordova\platforms\ios\platform_www
```

After that you should be able to find them in assets folder from apk:

[image]